# Intent.ACTION_CALL - "Mobile network not available"

Tags: android, android-intent

When I test my application with the emulator I get the following message: "Mobile network not available". Ofcourse I don't expect it to actually call from the emulator, but I want some sort of confirmation that it works.

In my application I use an intent like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode(input.getText().toString()))); 
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I also implement this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>` in the manifest-file.

Why is this?

EDIT: Seems like this only was a problem when I used GenyMotion. With the regular simulator, the call simulation worked.

Comment: Do you expect your emulator to have a **SIM**? can you place calls from it? can you even call your emulator with your phone? Isn't it normal, that **your emulator can't call**?

Comment: Did you try running on actual mobile instead of emulator?

Comment: Maybe the error message "Mobile network not available" is confirmation enought that it actually works...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not even a question.

Comment: I refer you my first line: "From what I've read this is an error between two interfaces, in this case my Google Pixel and the BT network I subscribe to."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check and update if it works. This is my assumption which may work since I have not tried it by myself.

Open another emulator and note down its port number and use something like this

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:5554")); // assuming the second emulator port number is 5554
```

I am assuming this because,  there is no sim card inserted in the emulator so you cannot call any real life phone number. But it is actually possible to dial one emulator from another using its port number using built in dialer app.

Comment: It isn't an emulator: "From what I've read this is an error between two interfaces, in this case my Google Pixel and the BT network I subscribe to."